# Ooyala Player SDK OoyalaPlayerLayoutController Android

Tags: android, android-layout, ooyala

I´m trying to get the height of the `OoyalaPlayerLayoutController` after I build my Ooyala player and attached the controller. I´ve tried with:

```
getLayout().getHeight()
```

and:

```
oyalaPlayer.getLayout().getLayoutParams().height
```

and:

```
playerLayout.getHeight()
```

Every time I get a value of `0`. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Wait for the player state change event

```
OoyalaPlayer mPlayer;
...

Observable o = new Observer() {
            @Override
            public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {
                trackProgress(mPlayer.getPlayheadPercentage());

                Log.wtf("state", mPlayer.getState());
if(mPlayer.getState() == READY)
doMeasure();
            }
        };

mPlayer.addObservable(o);
```

btw here is the list of the states availbale

```
 public static enum State {
        INIT,
        LOADING,
        READY,
        PLAYING,
        PAUSED,
        COMPLETED,
        SUSPENDED,
        ERROR;

        private State() {
        }
    }
```